# Equals method throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Good day,

I have created an object dynamic array and a delete method which deletes a particular object within that array. I have created another private method which works in case 2 objects with same surnames and initials are detected. 
Here is my code.

```
public Entry[] entryDirectory = new Entry[0];

@Override
public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
    int index = findFreeSpace();

    if (index >= 0) {
        entryDirectory[index] = newEntry;
    }
    else {
    entryDirectory = Arrays.copyOf(entryDirectory,
            entryDirectory.length + 1);
    entryDirectory[entryDirectory.length - 1] = newEntry;
    }
}

private int findFreeSpace() {

    for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {
        if (entryDirectory[i] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

private Entry[] findEntries(String name) {

    Entry[] returnEntries = new Entry[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {
        if ((entryDirectory[i].getSurname() + " " + entryDirectory[i]
                .getInitials()).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {

            returnEntries = Arrays.copyOf(returnEntries,
                    returnEntries.length + 1);
            returnEntries[returnEntries.length - 1] = entryDirectory[i];
        }
    }
    return returnEntries;
}

@Override
public void deleteEntry(String name) {

    if (findEntries(name).length == 1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {

            if (entryDirectory[i].equals(findEntries(name)[0])) {
                entryDirectory[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used the following code to test this out:

```
    d.addEntry(new Entry("a", "a", 1234));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("a", "b", 12345));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("a", "c", 123456));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("a", "d", 123456));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("a", "e", 123456));

    d.deleteEntry("a a");
```

A nullpointer exception is thrown when the deleteEntry method is used. However, if I would change the boolean logic in the if statement from the deleteEntry method to

```
(entryDirectory[i].getSurname() + " " + entryDirectory[i]
                    .getInitials()).equalsIgnoreCase(name)
```

the deleteEntry method would work. Why does the .equals() method display false in my case?

Cheers

Comment: Learn to use your debugger, and find by yourself. by executing the code step by step, and inspecting the variable values. Also, realize that each time you have findEntries(name) in the code, it executes the findEntries() method.

Comment: I am using JUnit testcase on this program and as I have mentioned that if I change the boolean logic inside the deleteEntry method; this program works. I am curious why it throws a nullpointer when the .equals(findEntries(name)) method is used.

Comment: And how does that prevent you from using your debugger?

Comment: In which line exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: second if statement inside the deleteEntry method and the if statement inside the findEntries method

Comment: Nizet I have never used a debugger before, I will give it a try then.

Comment: It throws a null pointer exception because you have a null pointer.  Duh!!  If you bothered to read the exception stack trace it would point at the exact line where the error occurs.  One of the pointers on that line is null.

Comment: I have read the stacktrace before posting this and the array which is returned by the findEntries method is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! But you should change the logic of your code really

```
private Entry[] findEntries(String name) {

    Entry[] returnEntries = new Entry[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {

        if (entryDirectory[i] != null) {

            if ((entryDirectory[i].getSurname() + " " + entryDirectory[i]
                    .getInitials()).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {

                returnEntries = Arrays.copyOf(returnEntries,
                        returnEntries.length + 1);
                returnEntries[returnEntries.length - 1] = entryDirectory[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return returnEntries;
}
```

Please note that you make entries of `entryDirectory` null in the following line :

```
if (entryDirectory[i].equals(findEntries(name)[0])) {
    entryDirectory[i] = null;// this is the source of exception
}
```

---

I even go one step further, cause after solving that issue you'll get another exception.
Interestingly as the conditions inside `findEntries` may not satisfy, so it may return an empty array so, you should change it into this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {
    if (findEntries(name).length != 0) {
        if (entryDirectory[i].equals(findEntries(name)[0])) {
            entryDirectory[i] = null;// this is the source of exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that it will work only for the boolean logic inside the if statement, but yeah... I was wrong. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

have you overriden the equals method in your Entry class ?

if not definitely it returns false.

so override equals method and add the logic of equality inside equals as below

```
public boolean equals(Entry o){

boolean result;
    if((o== null) || (getClass() != o.getClass())){
        result = false;
    } // end if
    else{
        Entry e= (Entry)o;
        result = surname.equals(o.surname) &&  initials.equals(o.initials);
    } // end else

    return result;

}
```